# What are the performance advantages in Angular to create a directive instead of using ng-include?

Tags: angularjs

```
<div ng-include="'blah.html'">

vs.

<blah> </blah>
```

What are the performance advantages to the latter?

Comment: Your question presumes that the difference is only about performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if you just want the content of the template, its faster to create a simple directive that just use `templateUrl`. However, ng-include offers some advance features that a simple directive don't have such as the `$includeContentLoaded` event and the `onload` call back.

Here is the [performance benchmark](http://jsperf.com/ng-include-vs-static-include) that prove `templateUrl` is faster. `dummy` is the simple directive